# Microsoft SQL 2005 active cluster node has 100% CPU load after clustering

Tags: sql-server-2005, cluster-computing, cpu-usage

Before moving to the SQL Server 2005 cluster we had on avarage 60% CPU load. After moving to active/passive cluster (with the exactly same hardware), the load on active node CPU is becoming 100% and after a while time-outs are comming from our web application. Any ideas what could be a couse?

Additional info:
OS: Windows Server 2008 Enterprise;
SQL: SQL Server 2005 SP3 Enterprise;
Both nodes has exactly the same hardware

Comment: Well, what process is using CPU?  Is it sqlservr.exe, or something else?

Comment: You may get better info on ServerFault.com

Comment: You'll need to check what the performance stats look like, before we can help much further. That is at OS and DB level.

Comment: What couters exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it's SO STRANGE, but installing SQL Server 2005 SP3 Comulative Update 6 helped!